# Probability of a point being withing a equilateral triangle

Tags: probability

A point is selected at random inside an equilateral triangle
with a side 1 mile (that means that, if X and Y are the coordinates of
the chosen point, then the joint density of X and Y is constant over
the triangle). What is the probability that the point will be within 1/4
mile of some corner of the triangle?

Answer (score 1):

One would think this would be the ratio of areas. The area within a distance $r$ from a corner is just:
$$A= \frac{60^\circ (\pi r^2)}{360^\circ}=\frac{\pi r^2}{6}$$ 
So the area of three corners is $\pi r^2 / 3$, assuming $2r$ is smaller than the side length, so that the circles don't overlap. In your case this condition is satisfied, since $2r=1/2 < 1$.
Now, if you know the area of a triangle, can you finish the calculation?